# Order By Count Query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the following code which retrieves the count of the following query:

```
<% @count = Model.find(:all, :conditions =>
              {:action => actions, :controller => tempController}).count %>
```

I'm just wondering how I get this query to order by the count retrieved going from highest to lowest.

Comment: Order what, exactly? Your query doesn't retrieve a list of things; it retrieves a single number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling Model from views is just against the MVC. This is the wrong way

```
<% @count = Model.where({:action => actions, 
                         :controller => tempController}).order("column_name").count %>
```